# What is the best way to update a group of rows in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

think my table is like this

```
+--------+-------------------+-----------+
| ID     | Type              |  nOrder   |
+--------+-------------------+-----------+
| 1      | A                 | 0         |
| 2      | A                 | 1         |
| 3      | A                 | 2         |
| 4      | B                 | 0         |
| 5      | B                 | 1         |
| 6      | B                 | 2         |
| 7      | B                 | 3         |
| 8      | B                 | 4         |
| 9      | C                 | 0         |
| 10     | C                 | 1         |
+--------+-------------------+-----------+
```

and i have an array like this

```
+--------+-------------------+-----------+
| ID     | Type              |  nOrder   |
+--------+-------------------+-----------+
| 5      | A                 | 0         |
| 4      | A                 | 1         |
+--------+-------------------+-----------+
```

i want to update my table with these new rows in laravel,
is there any way to this in laravel without a loop? if not how can i do it with sql statment.

in php and mysqli i could create a query of all of my updates query, then sending them in a query , a query with 10 update statement , now how could i do this in laravel???

Comment: Since you have the array, why you don't want to loop? You still need to loop to access the array contents.

Comment: because it's not a good solution to send database query in a loop, i want to do it just by one query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this using a single query in mySQL, you have 2 options.

**Option 1:** Use the [replace into](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html) mysql construct like so:

```
$query = "replace into {$table} values (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?)";
$insertArray = [[5, "A", 0], [4, "A", 1]];
DB::insert($query, array_flatten($insertArray));
```

**Option 2:** Use the [insert into on duplicate key](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) mysql construct like so:

```
$query = "insert into {$table} values (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?) on duplicate key update ID = VALUES(ID), Type = VALUES(Type), nOrder = VALUES(nOrder)";
$insertArray = [[5, "A", 0], [4, "A", 1]];
DB::insert($query, array_flatten($insertArray));
```

> The difference between the 2 constructs is that replace into either
>   inserts (for a new row) or deletes then inserts (for an existing row).
>   However, insert into on duplicate key performs an insert for a new row
>   and update for an existing row

You may use [this package](https://github.com/yadakhov/insert-on-duplicate-key) for both options

An alternative, if you need speed of execution but also don't want to use raw queries like this is to use [database transactions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/database#database-transactions)

Answer (score 0):

What about [Mass updates](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#updates)

```
Model::where('type', 'A')->where('nOrder', '<', 2)->update(['foo' => 'bar'])
```

Your attributes have to be set in `$fillable` in your model. In other words, you must add `$fillable = ['foo']` to your model.

Answer (score 0):

**IMO** There is no `"laravel way"` of doing something like this, At some level like this you have to iterate over `Array` or `Laravel Collection` to update individual records. Because these are updates and each having different Identity Column.

**On the other hand if your identity column matches multiple records** laravel supports [Mass Update](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#inserting-and-updating-models), i.e. in case your where clause matches more then one elements.

```
App\Flight::where('active', 1)
          ->where('destination', 'San Diego')
          ->update(['delayed' => 1]);
```

Comment: in php and mysqli i could create a query of all of my updates query, then sending them in a query , a query with 10 update statement , now how could i do this in laravel???

Comment: Nope there is no such thing like this in laravel.

Answer (score 0):

You can only update with same values for each record.

```
$values = [['Type' => 'A'],['nOrder' => '0']];
DB::table('table_name')->whereIn('id', [4, 5])->update($values);
```

Comment: this is a insert , how can i do it for updating ?

Comment: @AfshinEzadi You can only update with same values for each record.if you think this can be acheived with raw sql query you can always use `DB::raw()` in laravel.